# Inspect Ember.js: Get the type of an object (Class)?

Tags: ember.js

I use `console.log()` a lot, especially in combination with `Ember.inspect()`. But there's one thing I miss:

How can I find out the type of an object (Class)?

For example: Getting something like `<Sandbox.ApplicationController:ember288>` when inspecting `Ember.get("controller")`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you just want the model name (for example `app/models/comment.js` has the model name `comment`), you can use `thing.constructor.modelName`.

For example:

```
var aComment = this.get('store').createRecord('comment');
aComment.get('constructor.modelName') // => 'comment'
```

Comment: When I use that field in the template I get this error:
Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM

Answer (score 24):

I understand you are looking for a string for debugging purposes, but I originally came to this question wanting to know specifically how to get the type of the object, not a string describing the object.

Using the built in Javascript property constructor will yield the class used to construct the instance. For example you could do:

```
person = App.Person.create();
person.constructor // returns App.Person
person.constructor.toString() // return "App.Person"
```

Answer (score 18):

If you get `Class`, you can usually call `toString()` (or as a shortcut concat an empty string `+ ''`) to get something like `<Sandbox.ApplicationController:ember288>`

Answer (score 1):

Another useful feature (in chrome) is the `dir` command.

```
dir(App.User)
```

This will give you the full object information, rather than just the name.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that some of these answers suggested here only work in **development**. Once your code is in **production** most of those methods / class names will get *minified*.

```js
import Model from '@ember-data/model';

export default class Animal extends Model {
  // ...
}
```

So in **development**:

```js
const model = this.store.createRecord('animal');
model.constructor.name // returns Animal
```

in **production**:

```js
const model = this.store.createRecord('animal');
model.constructor.name // returns 'i' (or any other single letter).
```

To avoid this, use `constructor.toString()`

```js
const model = this.store.createRecord('animal');
model.constructor.toString() // returns 'model:animal'
```